# strtok behaving inconsistently

Tags: c, valgrind, strtok

I am trying to read data from a file, tokenize it and sort it, however `strtok` behaves erratically when I run it, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't and I get very short/odd tokens.

Valgrind seems to think it is because strtok is relying on an uninitialised value (I think):

```
==7069== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==7069==    at 0x40B61A3: strtok (strtok.S:160)  
==7069==    by 0x8048842: main (main.c:58)
```

Here is the function that I think valgrind is accusing:

```
char * getNextToken(char * line) {  
    char delim = ',';  
    return strtok(line, &delim);  
}
```

Could this be because line is `NULL` for most of my calls to `strtok`?

Here are my calls to the function:

```
strcpy(performer, getNextToken(inputLine));  
strcpy(title, getNextToken(NULL));  
strcpy(charMin, getNextToken(NULL));  
/*etc...*/
```

I have no idea what could be causing this and all the values I give `strtok` are what I am expecting. Also I will occasionally get a stack smashing error, I don't know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strtok` takes a null-terminated string for both arguments. You're not passing one for your delimiter. try this:

```
char * getNextToken (char * line){
    const char *delim = ",";
    return strtok(line, delim);
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: 8 years later and this helped me out. Simple explanation, too! Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

First answer has it right regarding strtok().  But beyond that, and possibly why you're getting "stack smashing errors", is because strtok will return a pointer to whatever token it finds, and if that's bigger than the array you've allocated for the destination for strcpy(), it will happily overflow it.

I would consider using strdup() instead of strcpy().